# regexp_replace instead of TRIM

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

**EDIT** - complete rewrite as per user comments.
First post here - trying to do this right.

I am looking to use a regex_replace instead of a TRIM in the following.

```
SELECT 
       'UPDATE '||quote_ident(c.table_name)||' SET '||c.COLUMN_NAME||'=TRIM('||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||')  
        WHERE '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||' ILIKE ''% '' ' AS script
FROM (
        SELECT 
           table_name,COLUMN_NAME
        FROM 
           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE 
           table_name LIKE 'my_%' AND (data_type='text' OR data_type='character varying')
     ) c;
```

which generates this statement:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field=TRIM(my_field);
```

The goal is to generate the following statement:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field=regexp_replace(my_field, '\s+$', '');
```

but my attempt:

```
SELECT 
               'UPDATE '||quote_ident(c.table_name)||' SET '||c.COLUMN_NAME||'=regexp_replace('||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||', '\s+$', '')  
                WHERE '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||' ILIKE ''% '' ' as script
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                   table_name,COLUMN_NAME
                FROM 
                   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE 
                   table_name LIKE 'my_%' AND (data_type='text' OR data_type='character varying')
             ) c;
```

is generating the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
    LINE 2: ...regexp_replace('||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||', '\s+$', '')...
                                                                 ^
```

Hoping to gain a little clarity in why this is not working. Thank you.

Comment: The regexp portion of the first `regexp_replace` in your question is fine (`\s+$`), but what's up with `||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||` in quotes? That's going to literally be that string; it's not going to interpolate the value. There's no actual syntax error anywhere in there, though.

Comment: I see now where you got the `||` bit from, in the question you linked to, but go re-read that; you're misinterpreting the source material. You just need: `regexp_replace(c.COLUMN_NAME, '\s+$', '')`...however that still doesn't explain the syntax error. Please include your entire SQL query instead of the partial text above.

Comment: This is looking like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Consider updating your question with what your ultimate goal is, including complete examples and complete error messages. The syntax you are trying to copy from that other question doesn't work like that.